# Failing to read data from firebase firestore using next.js getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to read data from firebase using nextjs but I get back an empty page. Even when I console log, nothing gets returned. This is how my code looks like

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "students");

function Card(props) {
    const { studentsData } = props
    
    return (
    <div>
        <p>This is just a test</p>
        {studentsData && studentsData.map(students => (
            <p>{students.name}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const students = await getDocs(reference);
    const studentsData = students.docs.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
    console.log(studentsData);

    return {
        props: { studentsData }
    }
}
export default Card
```

All I get back from this is just an empty page. Where could I be going wrong?.

Comment: Do your firestore rules allow reading without authentication?